# Unable to close tcp socket on event error at node server when client is not gracefully disconnects

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, events, tcp

I have writen a simple javascript chat application using tcp socket on node.js.

It works fine on local server (Ubuntu 16.04, Node version 8.7), but when deployed at **live server (Debian OS, Node version 8.7)**, application is not working properly.

**Problem** is that when **client's internet disconnects abruptly**, or **application is crushed**, node **server does not enter event-error**, to remove the client from lobby. If client ends the socket connection gracefully, server calls event-end, event-disconnect, or event-close to remove the socket from lobby and close the socket as well.

**NOTE:** No issue is faced when same code runs on local server. On local server, when disconnection is abrupt, code enters in **"error" event** and removes the client from lobby list.

Kindly, help me out, as I might be missing some thing.

```
    var tls = require('tls');
    var fs = require('fs');
    net = require('net');

    var options = {
        key  : fs.readFileSync('/root/server.key'),
        cert : fs.readFileSync('/root/server.cert')
    };

    // Keep track of devices
    var clients = [];
    var ip = [,];

    var server = tls.createServer(options, function (socket) {

        // Identify device
        socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort 

        socket.on('uncaughtException', function(er) {
           console.error(er.stack);
           socket.exit(1);
        });

        // Remove device from the list when connection dropped
        socket.on('error', function(error_inappropriate) {
             console.log('Device_Left: ', socket.name);
             clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
             console.log('Warning:', " " + socket.name + " inappropriate_con_closed. " +  error_inappropriate.message);
        });

        socket.on('close', function() {
           console.log('Event:', 'CLOSE event triggered, connection closed');
           clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
           console.log('Warning:', 'DISCONNECT event triggered, device disconnected');
           clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
        });

        socket.on('end', function () {
           clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
           broadcast(socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
        });

        // Handle incoming messages from devices
        socket.on('data', function (data) {
           broadcast(socket.name + "says: " + data);
        });

        // Send a message to all devices
        function broadcast(message, sender) {
           clients.forEach(function (client) {
              // Don't want to send it to sender
              if (client === sender) return;
              client.write(message);
           });
        }
    }).listen(443);
```

Comment: If the remote client crashes or shuts down abruptly, your server will only become aware of it during a **send** attempt to it. There´s no way for the server socket to determine that the other side disappeared without tryng to talk to it...

Comment: @C.Gonzalez can you please help me out, how can I tackle this in send attempt? need some working example, as I am new to node.js

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, the moment you call **broadcast**, it will make the **on.error** run  and the disconnected socket is gone...Nothing to change, all should work properly as soon as there is something to send. If activity is low, the disconnected socket will be in your lista for some time, no worries there either.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez,  The problem is that its not triggering **on.error** in live server thus not removing the client from lobby.